# Using Realm from npm on Electron JS app

Tags: realm, electron, npm-install

I am trying to use Realm imported with NPM but it fails.

I am using the Realm example for JavaScript:

```js
const Realm = require('realm');

// Define your models and their properties
const CarSchema = {
  name: 'Car',
  properties: {
    make:  'string',
    model: 'string',
    miles: {type: 'int', default: 0},
  }
};
const PersonSchema = {
  name: 'Person',
  properties: {
    name:     'string',
    birthday: 'date',
    cars:     'Car[]',
    picture:  'data?' // optional property
  }
};

Realm.open({schema: [CarSchema, PersonSchema]})
  .then(realm => {
    // Create Realm objects and write to local storage
    realm.write(() => {
      const myCar = realm.create('Car', {
        make: 'Honda',
        model: 'Civic',
        miles: 1000,
      });
      myCar.miles += 20; // Update a property value
    });

    // Query Realm for all cars with a high mileage
    const cars = realm.objects('Car').filtered('miles > 1000');

    // Will return a Results object with our 1 car
    cars.length // => 1

    // Add another car
    realm.write(() => {
      const myCar = realm.create('Car', {
        make: 'Ford',
        model: 'Focus',
        miles: 2000,
      });
    });

    // Query results are updated in realtime
    cars.length // => 2
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

And this is the error it throws:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module
>   '[path]/node_modules/realm/compiled/electron-v2.0_darwin_x64/realm.node'
>       at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename ([path]/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:473:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. ([path]/node_modules/realm/lib/index.js:102:28)
>       at Object. ([path]/node_modules/realm/lib/index.js:133:3)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:642:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:653:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:561:32)

Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

What happens is that electron specifies its own environment, while realm runtime loads its binaries based on this currently running environment.

However, when installing realm with npm, we fetch the binaries corresponding to the environment at the time of install, i.e. our node engine.

Therefore when running electron in dev mode, realm does not find the binary corresponding to the electron environment.

The usual workaround is to use the [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/) package and run its `install-app-deps` command, which will install the appropriate binaries for the electron target environment.

It is [usually recommended](https://www.electron.build/#quick-setup-guide) to make it an automatic script in your `package.json` file:

> To ensure your native dependencies are always matched electron version, simply add script :

```json
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
}
```

…so that it get run whenever you install a new package.

Comment: So I can't debug the app without install it?

Comment: The mentioned "install" is for your `realm` package, not your app.

Comment: Now it works even when I run without installation. Why?

Comment: I mean: I thought that Realm only works if I build a package with electron-builder. But it seems that it works too when I call to npm start

Comment: Once you run the `electron-builder install-app-deps` command, you download the realm binary for your electron version. Then even in electron dev mode (`npm start`) realm can find the appropriate binary.

Comment: I see... Thank you so much!

Comment: @ghybs its doesnt work on me :( . the error is the react-native dependency its not found

Comment: @cahyowhy Please feel free to open a new question with specific details of your issue.

Comment: @ghybs Why do I need `electron-builder install-app-deps` here, but `electron-rebuild` for other modules? I thought `electron-rebuild` fetches pre-built binaries as well, if possible?

Comment: Notice that there are only binaries for a few electron versions: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/Jenkinsfile#L13